# Given two tubes with different starting diameters that eventually become the same, which tube has the greater wall shear stress at the junction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, fluid-statics

I am running a few static computational fluid models and would like to get a better understanding of what I am doing prior to running the model. Provided below are two photos of the cross section of aforementioned tubes. A fluid (say, water) enters the tubes from the top and exits the tube through the bottom. **In the regions of this diameter change (the region of y-values from -20 cm to -20.2 cm, which one of these tubes would have a larger wall shear stress?**

Would the tube that has a larger change in diameter have a larger wall shear stress on it or the tube that has a smaller change in diameter? I understand wall shear stress/shear stress at the wall to be calculated  with this equation: [image], which takes into account dynamic viscosity and the spanwise/streamwise velocities at the given point of calculation.

[image: A. Tube of 2.27 cm starting diameter that goes into a 2.4 cm ending diameter]
[image: B. Tube of 2.1 cm starting diameter that goes into a 2.4 cm ending diameter]